# JavaScript Creating Index Mapping in Alphabetical Order

Tags: javascript, sorting, d3.js

I have a csv that's being loaded into my chord diagram rendered with D3:

```
origin    destination    value
banana    kiwi           10
apple     banana         5
pear      kiwi           12
```

This data is being passed in with this format:

```
console.log(data)
>> 0: {origin: "banana", destination: "kiwi", value: 10}
   1: {origin: "apple", destination: "banana", value: 5}
   2: {origin: "pear", destination: "kiwi", value: 12}
```

I am creating a matrix of `origin` and `destination` with `value` populating the matrix values. The first step of this is to create a mapping that ties fruit names to indexes:

```
var nameToIndex = {},
      names = [],
      matrix = [],
      n = 0,

  function recordName(name){
    if( !(name in nameToIndex) ){
            nameToIndex[name] = n++;
            names.push(name);
          }
        }

  data.forEach(function (d){
    recordName(d.origin);
    recordName(d.destination);
  });
```

After running this, here are sample `console.log()` commands:

```
console.log(nameToIndex[apple])
>> 2

console.log(nameToIndex[kiwi])
>> 1
```

The names are not alphabetically organized. How would I sort the names so that their indexes are also sorted? The results of the previous commands should be:

```
console.log(nameToIndex[apple])
>> 0

console.log(nameToIndex[kiwi])
>> 2
```

Apple is the first fruit alphabetically, and kiwi is the third fruit alphabetically.

I tried adding `names.sort()` to the `recordName()` function, but this just sorted `names` (predictably), and did not change the indexes of `nameToIndex`.

How do I sort `nameToIndex` so that the keys and values are sorted?

Comment: Possible for you to give an example of the `data` being passed and in the format it is being passed in please. Thank you.

Comment: I think I did with the table at the top. That's how it's being passed in. Please let me know if you need me to include something else!

Comment: So if you `console.log(data);` it looks exactly like that? or would it be formatted as an object or json?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for https://jsfiddle.net/xa6cnaff/ I have added an if condition to check if `n` is the same as the `data.length` so it will run on the last loop/cycle.

Comment: no, that doesn't appear to work. `console.log(nameToIndex['apple'])` still results in `2` rather than `0`.

Comment: This is kinda messy but I'm sure you can find a way to clean it up https://jsfiddle.net/xa6cnaff/1/

Comment: @NewToJS that seems to work with the play data - can't quite get it to extrapolate to my real data. @GerardoFurtado i guess i don't care about the order. i just need the key `apple` to tie to the `value` 0, the key `banana` to tie to the value `1`, etc.

Comment: So, all you need is an object with the fruit as the key and the index as the value, is that correct? And the fruits are the origin, the destination or all combined?

Comment: correct, with the lowest alphabetical fruit (i.e. apple) tied to the lowest number index (i.e. 0). the fruits are unique members of origin and destination combined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46626824/javascript-creating-index-mapping-in-alphabetical-order#comment80204709_46626824), all you want is an object with **all** the fruits as keys and their alphabetical positions as values.

In that case, we first get all the fruits...

```
var allFruits = [...new Set(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.origin
}).concat(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.destination
})))]
```

... and sort the resulting array:

```
.sort(function(a, b) {
    return d3.ascending(a, b)
});
```

After that, we just populate `nameToIndex` with a `forEach`:

```
allFruits.forEach(function(d, i) {
    nameToIndex[d] = i;
});
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var csv = `origin,destination,value
banana,kiwi,10
apple,banana,5
pear,kiwi,12`;

var data = d3.csvParse(csv);

var nameToIndex = {};

var allFruits = [...new Set(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.origin
}).concat(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.destination
})))].sort(function(a, b) {
  return d3.ascending(a, b)
});

allFruits.forEach(function(d, i) {
  nameToIndex[d] = i;
});

console.log(nameToIndex)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @slevy1 the code is running without any problem. The URL I'm using (`https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js`) is the official one. But thanks for that.

Comment: @slevy1 that is likely a bad extension or some kind of virus/malware locally. the D3 link is the official, current version. I would search for that error and see if you can find any fixes.